# Call method inside for loop with argument

Tags: angular

I can't figure out how I suppose to do in this scenario with my code here. I've looked through the documentation in Angular but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Gone through documentation about for loops.

```
<li *ngFor="let i of getItems()">
    {{ getObj(i).name }}
</li>
```

The item (i) should give an ID and the getObj(i).name should return the name of the object. The method takes a string as argument.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this work perfectly,

Here in TS file I've modified `getObj()` method which returns the name of the object and it will directly reflect name in the HTML .

Try this:

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let i of getItems()">
    {{ getObj(i)}}
</li>
```

TS:

```
getObj(i): string {
    return i.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li *ngFor="let i of getItems()">
    <span [innerHTML]="getObj(i).name"></span>
</li>
```

This is assuming that `getObj(i)` is a function that is returning an object having property `name`

However, The best approach would be storing `getObj(i)` in a valiable and looping through it in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display the result of the method you are trying to call on the fly. Try to getItems() inside ts code and then create a separate collection to hold the results of the method call you want to call for each i and loop through it, you can do it onInit or beforeViewInit.